# iOS 8 autolayout, VFL and margin equals or greater than

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, ios8

I'm experiencing problems with constraints in VFL on iOS 8, while on 6 and 7 it is all OK. This is the constraint:

```
H:|-margin-[_imageView]-(=>margin)-[_label]-margin-|
```

Both `_imageView_`and `_label` get their correct intrinsic width, and the margin grows as expected. I want to achieve

```
|-[_imageView]-------------------------------[some text]-|

|-[_imageView]---------------------------[a larger text]-|

|-[_imageView]-----------------------[a very large text]-|

|-[_imageView]-[a very very very very very very larg...]-|
```

It is OK visually but it raises a broken constraint exception:

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b856ee0 H:[UIImageView:0x7b8ef1f0]-(>=12)-[UILabel:0x7b8e7c60'Test']>
```

There is no ambiguity after printing `_autolayoutTrace`.

However, if the constraint involves only labels there is no problem at all:

```
H:|-margin-[_label1]-(=>margin)-[_label2]-margin-|
```

The problem could be solved following the next steps:

Changing the constraint removing `>=` and adding priorities:

```
H:|-margin-[_imageView]-(margin@750)-[_label]-margin-|
```

Setting the hugging priority of the `_imageView`

```
[_imageView setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Setting the compression resistance of the `_label`

```
[_label setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

With these rules there is no problem on any platform. Is all of this necessary on iOS 8? Is it a bug or I was doing it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the broken constraint comes from having too long a text string to honor the ">=12"; i.e. the width of the margins + image + text exceeds the width of the parent view. It's true that iOS 8 introduces layout margins, but I don't know enough about how those are affected by VFL statements to be of any help. Can you set your label's line height to be 0 so that it can expand vertically and still keep the horizontal constraint?

Comment: @NRitH the constraint is broken always, no matter the length of the text. I can't change the number of lines of the label, the text has to be truncated.

Comment: Can you post a full log and a stack trace of when it complains about the broken constraint? What happens if you don't set the content hugging priority and the compression resistance of the label?

Comment: Have you tried using preferredMaxLayoutWidth on UILabel? Setting this has helped me many times with auto layout issues. You could set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth to the width of the view mine the width of the imageView minus the padding you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating this. I've setup a quick example from scratch and it seems to behave as desired for me, using the following: `[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-margin-[imageView]-(>=margin)-[label]-margin-|" options:0 metrics:@{@"margin": @10} views:bindings]];`

Comment: @petehare My view is inside a table header, that is a little bit special with AL. Could it be related?
HectorMatos, I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've started project from scratch and here is my code (which actually works fine):

```
UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 160)];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[topView addSubview:imageView];

self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 80, 200, 32)];
self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
self.label.text = @"some text";
self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[topView addSubview:self.label];


self.tableView.tableHeaderView = topView;

NSDictionary *views = @{@"imageView":imageView, @"label":self.label};

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-margin-[imageView(40)]-(>=margin)-[label]-margin-|" options:0 metrics:@{@"margin": @30} views:views];
NSArray *imageConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[imageView(160)]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray *textConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-40-[label]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
NSArray *topConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[topView(320)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(topView)];

[topView addConstraints:constraints];
[topView addConstraints:imageConstraints];
[topView addConstraints:textConstraints];
[topView addConstraints:topConstraints];
```

I think your main problem is that you don't turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` which produces `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout` (which I've never met prior to iOs8). I haven't found a place where it is good documented, but there are numbers of question regarding that constraint.

I've also created github repo, so you can try it yourself: https://github.com/Nikita2k/constraintsTest

Additionally, you can take a look at WWDC2014 video - What's new in Table and Collection Views (~20min). There are some info, that you can see `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout` problem now, but it will be fixed later. Also, you can try playing with `rowHeight` as all ios8 tableViews from storyboard (or xib) should explicitly set

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

I'm not sure, will it help in this particullar case or not, but give it a try too!